# Download pdf loop

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to download several pdfs from the same site using a python 3.5 but I get to download just the first pdf and it goes into a loop.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

first = int(input('First:'))
last = int(input('Last:'))

if first <= last:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.netapp.com/us/media/tr-" + str(first) +".pdf")
    file = open(str(first) + ".pdf", 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
    response.close()
    first = first + 1
else:
    print("Completed")
```

Comment: What do you mean "it goes into a loop"? There are no loops in your code, but there should be one, as Namit's answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` instead of an `if`. `if` will only check for the condition once, and download the file, it is a branching operator. `while` is a looping operator.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

first = int(input('First:'))
last = int(input('Last:'))

while first <= last:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.netapp.com/us/media/tr-" + str(first) +".pdf")
    file = open(str(first) + ".pdf", 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
    response.close()
    first = first + 1
print("Completed")
```

Comment: Do you may know how to address "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found"?

Comment: @CarlosLozano This means the url you are fetching is not correct and not found on the server website.

Comment: Yes, some files are not available. I'm checking the documentation for urllib but I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: You could add a try except block inside while loop, which catches urllib.error.HTTPError, in case page is not available, just ignore it.